# What is the use of state bits(most significant 8 bits) in the measured width/height ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, android-viewgroup

The most significant 8 bits of the measured width/height integer is allotted for measured state. In those state bits 1 bit is used to identify if the measured width/height is too small. 
Can anyone explain whether there are more uses with those state bits? 
Are those bits kept for more complex measuring operations? 
Are there any tutorials which explain these things in detail?

Thank you :)